# Changing the Host passed to the backend

Tags: regex, nginx, hostname

I have my frontend server running nginx. The backend is on another machine on the same VPN. This is its config:

```
server {
    listen   80;
    server_name *.vpn.domain.com;

    location / {
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
        proxy_pass http://10.8.25.102:8100/;
        proxy_redirect http://10.8.25.102:8100/ http://$server_name/;
    }   
}
```

I would like to pass a different host to the backend... I'd like the backend to receive, for requests done to`subdomain.vpn.domain.com` the host `subdomain.local.domain.com`

Is there any way to do this? I'm looking for a regexp substitution (or even a substring substitution) but I'm having surprisingly little success... I thought it would be a piece of cake. I think the solution would be in the lines of

```
server {
    listen   80;
    server_name *.vpn.domain.com;

    set $my_host $http_host;
    replace $my_host .vpn. .local.

    location / {
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $my_host;
        proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
        proxy_pass http://10.8.25.102:8100/;
        proxy_redirect http://10.8.25.102:8100/ http://$server_name/;
    }   
}
```

It's just that I haven't found yet the proper syntax for `replace $my_host .vpn. .local.` I don't really care about multiple substitutions... I won't have `a.vpn.a.vpn.domain.com`

Comment: I don't really know much about nginx, but I think this page might have some examples that you could extrapolate from: https://blog.engineyard.com/2011/useful-rewrites-for-nginx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally figured it out, I can do

```
if ($http_host ~ ^(.*)\.vpn\.(.*)$) {
    set $my_host $1.local.$2;
}
```

And then, as there're CSRF validations in place, I also need to rewrite the `Referer`... so this is how it ended up looking

```
server {
    listen   80;
    server_name *.vpn.domain.com;

    set $my_host $http_host;
    if ($http_host ~ ^(.*)\.vpn\.(.*)$) {
        set $my_host $1.local.$2;
    }

    set $referer $http_referer;
    set $referer_host no;
    if ($http_referer ~ ^(https?://)([^/]+)(/.*)$) {
        set $referer_host $2;
        set $rewritten_referer $1$my_host$3;
    }
    if ($referer_host = $http_host) {
        set $referer $rewritten_referer;
    }

    location / {
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $my_host;
        proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
        proxy_set_header Referer $referer;
        proxy_set_header IS_SECURE no;
        proxy_pass http://10.8.25.102:8100/;
        proxy_redirect https://$my_host/ https://$http_host/;
        proxy_redirect http://$my_host/ http://$http_host/;
    }
}
```